# Is there a way to cap the amount of weight that a type of extrinsic can consume in a block?

Tags: weight, fee

My understand in substrate is that there are three types of dispatches, normal, operational, and mandatory.

This types of dispatch classes can consume a portion of the total weight in a block.

I can use `AvailableBlockRatio` to set the percentage that normal transactions can consume in a block.

Is there a way to extend that functionality. I want to limit the amount of weight an extrinsic can consume in a block.

I would like to further divide the allocated weight for normal dispatch classes.

For example, when attempting to add a transaction in a block, if the weight limit allocated for that transaction has been reached the transaction get added back into the transaction pool.

Answer (score 1):

A transaction being "feeless" is not something that is tracked in the pipeline, and thus not something that can be tracked using the same primitives and tools as we use to limit the weight of a block.

Instead, you will need to build your own set of custom logic to handle this.

For example, you can build a pallet, through which users can submit free transactions, and that pallet keeps track of how much weight it has used so far that block, and starts returning an error if too much weight is used in a single block.

Comment: You mean to proxy each extrinsic call? Like `custom_payment_pallet::Dispatch(call)` which then stores the weight used by `call`?

Comment: I might have mislead you on accident. I used a feeless extrinsic as an example. What I want to do is limit the weight of a particular extrinsic or a set of extrinsic in a block.

Comment: In the example above, if I were to implement a pallet that keeps track of weight consumed in a block and it errors out. As a result, users would get charged a fee because of the failure?

Perhaps, I am wrong, but I thought that weights were checked at the transaction pool before being added in a block. In the above example this happens after a transaction was added to be part of a block?